# im implementing network connectivity in my project but navgation not work perfectly

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to listen network connectivity on my whole project  this is work perfect but child return alway homePage when connection restored i want to navigate to current widget im using #InternetConnectionChecker dependency

```
GetMaterialApp(
            // initialBinding: DataBinding(),
             navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
          builder: (context , child){
            return StreamBuilder<InternetConnectionStatus>(
              stream:  InternetConnectionChecker().onStatusChange,
              builder: (context , snapshot){
                final connectivityResult = snapshot.data;
                print("result"+connectivityResult.toString());
                if(connectivityResult.toString()=="InternetConnectionStatus.disconnected") {
                  return NoInternet();
                }
                return child!;
              },
            );
          },
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: Themes.light,
           home:HomePage(deviceAddress: ''));
```

```
// global context class

class NavigationService {
  static GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below written code

The [data_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/data_connection_checker) package is used in it

```
     Future<bool> isInternet() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
      
      if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        return true;
      } 
else {
        return false;
      }
    } 
else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      
      if (await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        return true;
      } 
else {
        return false;
      }
    } 
else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

**You can return the statement as you want, like alert message or navigation to 'No Network' Screen**

Comment: can i used in main file for whole application

Comment: You have to code in VIewController class
Join iOS Community on WhatsApp : https://chat.whatsapp.com/G2ErXevhRPu35Pzu88GDuj